# $.ajax Not Working Properly in my code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've tried many different ways (this has taken 3 days) to use the Javascript ajax command to send form values to a php script but, my page still reloads and nothing gets inserted into my database. I get no errors, the scripts run but produce no results. To keep this post relatively short I put the HTML in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jBEHay8u) just in case anyone needs/wants to see it.

Here is my php script:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
$link = mysqli_connect(localhost, <removed>, <removed>, <removed>);

function val_data($data){
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data);
  return $data;
}

$type = val_data($_POST['type']);
$size = val_data($_POST['size']);
$date = val_data($_POST['datepicker']);
$message = val_data($_POST['message']);
$steam = val_data($_SESSION['steamid']);
//Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO requests (type, size, fdate, steam64id, message) VALUES ('$type', '$size', '$date', '$steam', '$message')";
$query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
function hideModal() {
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on('submit', '#myModal', function() {
      var error = "";
      var type = document.getElementById("type").val();
      var size = document.getElementById("size").val();
      var date = document.getElementById("datepicker").val();
      var message = document.getElementById("message").val();

      if(type == "") {
         error = "A Job type is required";
         document.getElementById("sparam").innerHTML = error;
         $("type").focus();
         return false;
      }

      if(size == "") {
         error = "A Job size is required";
         document.getElementById("sparam").innerHTML = error;
         $("size").focus();
         return false;
      }

      if(date == "") {
         error = "A desired completion date is required";
         document.getElementById("sparam").innerHTML = error;
         $("date").focus();
         return false;
      }

      if(message == "") {
         error = "A description of the job is required";
         document.getElementById("sparam").innerHTML = error;
         $("message").focus();
         return false;
      }

      $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'ajaxsubmit.php',
         data: {
            type:type,
            size:size,
            date:date,
            message:message
         }, 
         success: function(res) {
            $('#sparam').html("Thanks! We'll be in touch soon");
            setTimeout(hideModal, 5000);
         }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("type").val()`: `.val()` is a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/val), not a native DOM element method. Look at your javascript console you should be seeing errors

Comment: @PatrickEvans The only things in my javascript console are warnings from bootstrap & recaptcha.

Comment: Because your page is being reloaded, turn on the preserve log option (in Chrome at least) and it will not clear the log after navigation

Comment: Right but when you submit ... error will get thrown preventing the `return false` because of those invalid methods and that's what is happening

Comment: Note...if you were to put `event.preventDefault()` at beginning of submit handler...the errors that prevent `return false` wouldn't matter with regards to the page reloading. Default event would be prevented first

Comment: Ah, I see the error now. So I should use `.value`, correct? I'm pretty sure it's a native DOM element.

Comment: Or use jQuery for all of it...less to write ... easy to read..... `document.getElementById("type").value` would become `$('#type').val()`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, that works!

Comment: For some reason `mysqli_real_escape_string` turns all of my values to null. Never seen that happen before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case to point out using `event.preventDefault()` is safer   than using `return false` and also makes debugging easier.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myModal', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // form won't submit if errors thrown after this
```

Any error that gets thrown prior to that `return false` will block remaining code within the function and since false isn't returned the browser will submit form and reload page...and the `return` has to be after everything else, at the end of the event handler

If this does happen it's harder to debug since the errors thrown only hit the console for an instant before page and  console get cleared...making it more difficult to debug those errors

When you prevent the default first, then any errors in your code afterwords aren't good but the browser won't submit the form. However the console doesn't get cleared and you can spot the errors quickly

---

**Actual problem:**

You need to change the `val()` method which is for jQuery objects not DOM nodes to `value` or simplify the dom searches using jQuery

```
var type = document.getElementById("type").val();
```

Should be either:

```
var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
```

Or

```
var type = $("#type").val();
```